# How to add error alert if provided choice is none of rock, paper, scissors? How to make the whole code shorter?

Tags: javascript

How to add error alert if provided choice is none of rock, paper, scissors? How to make the whole code shorter?

```js
function game (inputOne, inputTwo){
  
  function result(inputOne, inputTwo){
    if (inputOne === inputTwo){
      return '0';
    }
    if (inputOne === 'rock'){
      if (inputTwo === 'scissors'){
        return '2';
      } else {
        return '1';
      }
    }
    if (inputOne === 'paper'){
      if (inputTwo === 'rock'){
        return '2';
      } else {
        return '1';
      }
    }
    if (inputOne === 'scissors'){
      if (inputTwo === 'paper'){
        return '2';
      } else {
        return '1';
      }
    }
  }
  
  function checkResult(){
    if (result(inputOne, inputTwo) === '0'){
      return 'Tie!';
    }
    if (result(inputOne, inputTwo) === '1'){
      return 'Player 2 won!'
    }
    if (result(inputOne, inputTwo) === '2'){
      return 'Player 1 won!';
    }
  }
  
  return checkResult(); 
}

console.log(game('rock', 'paper'));
```

When I try to write the code shorter like per example below, function is not working correctly:

```js
if (inputOne === 'scissors' && inputTwo === 'paper'){
      return '2';
    } else {
      return '1';
    }
 }
```

Comment: to make it shorter you can use ternary operators too.
return((inputOne === 'scissors' && inputTwo === 'paper') ? "2" : "1");

Comment: @gatopreto Regarding your 2nd snippet of code, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a suggestion to make the code shorter:

```js
function game(inputOne, inputTwo) {
  const rules = {
    rock: 'scissors',
    paper: 'rock',
    scissors: 'paper',
  };

  if (inputOne === inputTwo) {
    return 'Tie';
  }
  return rules[inputOne] === inputTwo ? 'Player 1 won!' : 'Player 2 won!';
}

const player1 = prompt('Player 1 choice: ');
const player2 = prompt('Player 2 choice: ');
console.log(game(player1, player2));
```

To handle invalid input you may do this:

```js
function game(inputOne, inputTwo) {
  const rules = {
    rock: 'scissors',
    paper: 'rock',
    scissors: 'paper',
  };

  const valid = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

  if (!valid.includes(inputOne) || !valid.includes(inputOne)) {
    const errorMessage = 'Invalid input!';
    alert(errorMessage);
    return errorMessage;
  }

  if (inputOne === inputTwo) {
    return 'Tie';
  }
  return rules[inputOne] === inputTwo ? 'Player 1 won!' : 'Player 2 won!';
}

const player1 = prompt('Player 1 choice: ');
const player2 = prompt('Player 2 choice: ');
console.log(game(player1, player2));
```

I return the errorMessage because a string is expected.

Comment: Don't forget the question in the title about handling invalid choices.